# Webpack: Issue loading external css files in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack to create a production build which will contain minified JS and confined CSS. But when I try to run my build none of the external css sheets load, although build process was successful.

In my resultant build folder all of the assets like css, images are placed on root.

Here is my webpack.production.congig file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry:  __dirname + "/app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65
              },
              // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
              optipng: {
                enabled: true,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              // the webp option will enable WEBP
              webp: {
                quality: 75
              }
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/index.tmpl.html"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ]

}
```

And here is what my index template look like:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="./app/resources/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link type="text/css" src="style.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'>
    </div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Build folder's content looks like:

[image: Build folder structure]

Comment: 1) Are you saying the problem is that index template is failing to load the resources (ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)? Or can you show us the exact error the console is displaying?


2) Are you moving your assets into folders once it's built? Because it seems like index can't find the assets . Btw you should have your project structured in Webpack to avoid having all assets on the root when the build is completed.

Comment: 1) No warning or error in console.
2) I am not copying my assets manually in my build folder. But such assets are already in build in root.

Comment: So if you have `style.css` and `bundle.js` next to index.html and no error, then everything is loading fine. The problem is not with Webpack but on `bundle.js`.  It seems `<div id='root'>` is empty, so maybe you are not rendering the app correctly in the div. Can you show us `bundle.js`?

Comment: Its an uglified  file, with a lot of  code in it. Let me share snap of my build folder's content.

Comment: Oh yeah I meant to check `/app/index.js` not the bundle. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the app itself. Is everything working fine in development?

Comment: Yeah development env working fine.

Comment: hmm let's do this: comment everything in app/index.js and just leave `console.log('Working');`. Then run the production build again and open the index file and check the console.

Comment: JS is working fine As I able to navigate through my application. Only issue is styling and images is not showing up

Comment: so if you comment everything in style.css and just leave `body {
  display: none;
  background: red;
}` it doesn't show the red screen?

Comment: Aforementioned styling is working...... Problem is I have several css files and using webpack plugin I confined them in to a single css file named style.css. Now when such css is trying to be accessed across the app, its not working.

Comment: It's normal if you have several css and using webpack to group them into one minified css file. However it's hard to debug the problem since we are on the blind here. Can you show how index looks like if you run it from the  production build vs showing the app running in development.

Comment: Just added the snaps

Comment: Let;s take the menu for example. Can you show us the Component and/or how are you loading its css and show us the css itself. Also make sure for example if you have a `menu.css` with let's say this rule: `.menu { background-color: red; }` , that this rule can be found in the minified `style.css`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lies at my webpack configuration where while using **css-loader** I should have enable modules to **true**

Here's is updated part of my config.

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              query: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            },
            {
             loader: "postcss-loader",
              options: {
                config: {
                  path: './postcss.config.js'
                }
              }
            }

          ]
        })
      }
```